# Issues with precompiled headers?

Tags: c++

Hopefully someone can help because I'm lost.  When running my program earlier, it worked fine, now for some reason I get the error message

> fatal error C1010: unexpected end of file while looking for precompiled header. Did you forget to add '#include "stdafx.h"' to your source?

which I did include the header. The goal was to create a program which prints the time and date and be able to input the size of the window and font and background color having two different files. The first file is as follows.

```
#include "TimeClass.h"
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Class to help with the usage of time.

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
CTimeClass::CTimeClass()
{
// Notice that the time is stored whenever this time object is created. 
// Use this to your advantage in "main".

// "m_st" holds the time and date information.
GetLocalTime(&m_st);
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
CTimeClass::~CTimeClass()
{
// Empty - Nothing to destroy here.
}
short CTimeClass::Year()
{
// Place your code here to return the year as a short.
ConsoleTime ct;
short year = ct.wYear;
return year;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
string CTimeClass::Month()
{
ConsoleTime ct; 
int month = cm.wMonth;
if (month == 0)
    return "January";
else if (month == 1)
    return "February";
else if (month == 2)
    return "March";
else if (month == 3)
    return "April";
else if (month == 4)
    return "May";
else if (month == 5)
    return "June";
else if (month == 6)
    return "July";
else if (month == 7)
    return "August";
else if (month == 8)
    return "September";
else if (month == 9)
    return "October";
else if (month == 10)
    return "November";
else if (month == 11)
    return "December";
else
    return "error";
// Place your code here to return the month as a string.
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
short CTimeClass::Day()
{
ConsoleTime ct;
short day = ct.wDay;
return day;

// Place your code here to return the day as a short.
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    string CTimeClass::DayOfWeek()
{
 ConsoleTime ct;
int day == st.wDayOfWeek;

if (day == 0)
    return "Sunday";
else if (day == 1)
    return "Monday";
else if (day == 2)
    return "Tuesday";
else if (day == 3)
    return "Wednesday";
else if (day == 4)
    return "Thursday";
else if (day == 5)
    return "Friday";
else if (day == 6)
    return "Saturday";
else
    return "error";
// Place your code here to return the day of the week as a string.
}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
short CTimeClass::Hour()
{
ConsoleTime ct;
short hour = ct.wHour;
return hour;
// Place your code here to return the hour as a short.
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
short CTimeClass::Minute()
{
ConsoleTime ct; 
short minute = ct.wMinute;
return minute;
// Place your code here to return the minute as a short.
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
short CTimeClass::Second()
{
ConsoleTime ct;
short second = ct.wSecond;
return second;
// Place your code here to return the second as a short.
}
```

Below is my second file.

```
// ConsoleWindowClock.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console 
  application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "ConsoleClass.h"
#include "TimeClass.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
int width;
int height;
int fontsize;
int text;
int background;
int userclass;
int time;

userclass.ConsoleColor(text, background);
userclass.ConsoleWindowSize(width, height);
userclass.FontSize(fontsize);

cout << "This is the console window clock" << endl;

cout << "Please enter the window size in characters: " << endl;
cin >> width;
cin >> height;

cout << "Please enter the font size: " << endl;
cin >> fontsize;

cout << "Enter the Text color (0=Red, 1=Green, 2=Blue, -1=Random): " << 
endl;
cin >> text;

cout << "Enter the background color (0=Red, 1=Green, 2=Blue, -1=Random): " 
<< endl;
cin >> background;


while (true) 
    {
    cout << "The time is: " << time.Hour() << ":" << time.Minute() << ":" << 
time.Second() << endl;
    cout << "The day of the week is: " << time.DayOfWeek() << endl;
    cout << "The month, day, and year are: " << time.Month() << " " << 
time.Day() << ", " << time.Year() << endl;

    Sleep(1000);

    }


return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, sorry for the long post.

Comment: Did you include `stdafx.h` into both source files? It does not seem to be the case for the first one.

Comment: I tried that, still the same issue

Answer (score 1):

You have messed up comments:

```
// ConsoleWindowClock.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console 
  application.
//
```

should be

```
// ConsoleWindowClock.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console 
// application.
```

Also you should include precompiled header before `TimeClass.h` in the first file.

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#include "TimeClass.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you reviewed your "TimeClass.h"? I had seen similar error which was originated from the .h file.

I know this should be in a comment but don't have enough repute for that :(

Comment: I did, unfortunately I'm not seeing anything.  The odd part is that it was running earlier, then I closed the program, reopened it, and now this is happening.

Comment: Please check for any #if / #ifdef and if it have matching #endif. Many times we miss the pair

Comment: @CollinLynch, Have you checked [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7fz9ckx(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: I saw that earlier, did that and still nothing, idk what's wrong